# JS drawing Images on Canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm trying to past multiple images on separate Canvas layers that are stacked upon each other yet the images aren't drawing on the canvas. Can someone help me out with what I am missing?
Thanks

CSS

```
   .positionCanvas{
            position: absolute;
            left:0;
            right:0;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    }

    #logoCanvas{
        position: relative;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="logoCanvas">
        <canvas class="positionCanvas" width="300" height="300" id="outerRingCanvas">

        </canvas>
        <canvas class="positionCanvas" width="300" height="300" id="crossCanvas">

        </canvas>
        <canvas class="positionCanvas" width="300" height="300" id="innerRingsCanvas">

        </canvas>
        <canvas class="positionCanvas" width="300" height="300" id="centreCanvas">

        </canvas>

    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var outerRing = document.getElementById('outerRingCanvas'),
    cross = document.getElementById('crossCanvas'),
    innerRings = document.getElementById('innerRingsCanvas'),
    centre = document.getElementById('centreCanvas');



var outerCtx = outerRing.getContext('2d'),
    crossCtx = cross.getContext('2d'),
    innerRingsCtx = innerRings.getContext('2d'),
    centreCtx = centre.getContext('2d');

var ctxArray = [outerCtx, crossCtx, innerRingsCtx, centreCtx];

var outerImg = new Image(),
    crossImg = new Image(),
    innerRingsImg = new Image(),
    centreImg = new Image();

var imgArray = [outerImg, crossImg, innerRingsImg, centreImg];

    outerImg.src = "logo_ring.png";
    crossImg.src = "logo_cross.png";
    innerRingsImg.src = "logo_centre_rings.png";
    centreImg.src = "logo_centre.png";
placeLogos(ctxArray);
crossCtx.drawImage(crossImg, 0, 0, 300, 300);



function placeLogos(array){
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        array[i].drawImage(imgArray[i], 100, 100, 100, 100);
        array[i].fillStyle = "rgba(233,100,10,0.2)"
        array[i].fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);

    }
}
```

Comment: Double check the paths to your images. Your code works - http://jsfiddle.net/L7g8h/

Comment: My images are in the same directory as the js file and all the names are correct. its quite odd.

Comment: The fiddle I've posted is your code. Are you running the page over a webserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the onload mechanism as image loading is asynchronous. If you're not using this the image may not be fully loaded when you try to use them leaving the canvas(es) blank.

```
...

var imageCount = 4;

outerImg.onload = loader;
crossImg.onload = loader;
innerRingsImg.onload = loader;
centreImg.onload = loader;

outerImg.src = "logo_ring.png";
crossImg.src = "logo_cross.png";
innerRingsImg.src = "logo_centre_rings.png";
centreImg.src = "logo_centre.png";

function loader() {
    imageCount--;

    if (imageCount === 0) {
        placeLogos(ctxArray);
        crossCtx.drawImage(crossImg, 0, 0, 300, 300);
    }
}
```